# Ho to get API.AI params in HttpServletRequest?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I am building an Action. My back end is deployed on heroku an duses Java/Spring Boot. I am tying to print all request parameters but I can't see the requuest param set by API.AI

```
"result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Weather in Portland",
    "action": "yahooWeatherForecast",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "geo-city": "Portland"
    }
```

I am neither getting "result" not "geo-city" in request.getParameter call. How is API AI setting these values?

Comment: Can you provide us more informations :
Did you set a webhook for your intent ?
Is your controller being called ?

Answer (score 0):

When you test your Action on API AI, parameters are passed in the POST request body.